# Warning for wrong styles in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How to we get warning or error messages from styled-components, when we write some wrong styles?
Also do we have any linting tool for style components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you get style warnings when a certain property doesn't exist. For example if you apply

```
{
align-items: center
}
```

to a `<Text/>` you'll get a warning that this property doesn't exist on type Text.

For style linting I recently came across stylelint which helps with linting in styled-components. 
Here's the link to read more about it
https://medium.com/styled-components/announcing-production-ready-linting-for-styled-components-58adcdc4a97